# scala jrebel superclass change

Tags: scala, compiler-construction

I'm using JRebel with Scala and I'm quite frequently experiencing the need for restart of server due to the fact that JRebel is unable to load a class if the superclass was changed. This is done mainly when I change anonymous functions as I can deduce from the JRebel error desription: 
`Class 'mypackage.NewBook$$anonfun$2' superclass was changed from 'scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1' to 'scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2' and could not be reloaded`.
 Is there any way, how can I design my code to avoid this? Does scala compiler take the functions, numbers them from one as they appear in source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers that are changing refer to the number of function arguments. An `AbstractFunction1` is a one-argument function, while `AbstractFunction2` is a two-argument function.  One way to work around this would be to curry or tuple your functions so that they're always one-argument functions.

And, yes, anonymous functions are automatically named as you suggested.  If you insert a new anonymous two-arg function before an existing anonymous one-arg function, it will appear as if the type of the original function changed.